# design problem in handling dynamic input from end user

Tags: java, design-patterns, runtime, server-side, factory-pattern

I am writing an application for different geometrical types of fuel tanks.

I have a design problem that only at runtime I will receive the exact type of tank from the end user; and I don't know how to create/handle a dynamic object on the server side.

For example, a tank can have 3 geometrical types of head: conical, dished, and flat. Each type  of head needs to be validated differently.

I have created a parent class named `Head` that has all common parameters to all geometrical types of head (diameter, thickness etc.). Each child class (`Conical`, `Dished` and `Flat`) extends `Head` and has its own instance variables.

The end user will choose, for example, a tank with conical heads and input all the required parameters and send it to the server for validation.

At this stage I am stuck. I don't know how to handle the dynamic data. I got a suggestion to use *Factory* design pattern; but because every class has different 
variables, I don't think that is the right direction.

code without constructor and get/set methods

```
public class Head {
    private float headThickness=0;
    private float headThicknessTolerance=0;

    private ShapeOfHead headShape;
    private float knuckleRadius=0;
    private int numberOfHeadPieces=4;
    private HeadSide headSide;

    private Figure8_1WeldingDetails headLongitudinalWeld;
    private Figure9_1WeldingDetails headCircumferentialWeld;

    private Bracing headBracing;
}

public class DishedHead extends Head {
    private float dishedHeadDepth;  
}

public class ConicalHead extends Head {
    private float conicalHeadHeight;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use Builder design pattern: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/builder-design-pattern-tutorial/

Comment: I think this question is too broad to answer, since there are innumerable potential solutions, and SO is intended for answers rather than advice. Possibly https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be a better venue for this type of question.